# phpSpreadsheet to mPDF text rotation

Tags: php, mpdf, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to achieve text rotation after parsing spreadsheets to PDF. Currently, I am setting text rotation like `$this->getAlignment($address)->setTextRotation(90);` and in excel it works fine (picture below):

[image]

however, in generated PDF the text rotation isn't working:

[image]

I found out that mPDF supports setting a text rotation like `style="text-rotate: 45"` or as custom html attribute `text-rotate="45"`, but I don't see any option of manually setting CSS property.

Comment: may be style="transform: rotate(45deg)" ?

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei mPDF supports only `text-rotate`

Comment: Try to apply the text-rotate attribute only to specific td tags in which you want to rotate the text.

Comment: "but I don't see any option of manually setting CSS property."...

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Did you found a solution?